# SQL DISTINCT WITH TWO VARIABLES

Tags: php, html, jquery, sql, messaging

I am creating a messaging site, with php and ajax.

there is a problem on getting conversations.

The problem is that whenever two user chat between them there is two distinct rows with id;

example

A and B is chattting and only written 4 messages to each other

messages database is like this

```
id senderid recieverid 
1   a.id      b.id
2   b.id      a.id
3   b.id      a.id
4   a.id      b.id
```

My aim is getting records with this code

```
SELECT DISTINCT senderid, recieverid from messages WHERE (senderid = '".$pageowner."' OR recieverid='".$pageowner."')
```

the $pageowner is the user who logged in;

with this method i get two same conversations

a<->b and b<->a

and the code gives me two conversations on the page i want to only get one result;

my whole php code is like this

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    include 'config.php';
    $pageowner = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT senderid, recieverid from messages WHERE (senderid = '".$pageowner."' OR recieverid='".$pageowner."')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $conversations = mysqli_fetch_all($result);

    $output = "";
    foreach($conversations as $conversation){     
        $senderonmessages = $conversation[0];
        $recieveronmessages = $conversation[1];
        if($pageowner == $senderonmessages){
            $convname = $recieveronmessages;
        }else{
            $convname = $senderonmessages;
        }
        $sql = "SELECT id, name, surname, userimage FROM users WHERE id='".$convname."' ORDER BY id" ;
        $resconv = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resconv);
        $output .= '
                    <div class="conversationuser" id='.$user['id'].'>
                        <img src="'.$user['userimage'].'">
                        <span id="status"></span>
                        <div class="conv-info">
                            <h4><a href="">'.$user['name'].' '.$user['surname'].'</a></h4>
                            <p>Axirinici yazdigim mesaj <span id="time">10:34 AM</span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="conv-additional-info">
                            <span id="notif">1</span>
                            <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
    }
    echo $output;
 }
```

Comment: What do you want to get? You are open to SQL injections, use parameterized queries and prepared statements. `id, name, surname, userimage` could also be done with a `join` on first query.

Comment: i want to get one row for a conversation  the database gives me two records from a to b and from b to a but i only want one

Comment: When you run query in DB you get 8 rows or 4? Issue could be the fetch all returning numeric and associative because return method isnt defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your sql injection problem first. If you don't do that, you won't have any data in your database to worry about because somebody will drop it.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Also, your query gives you exactly what you are asking for: `DISTINCT senderid, recieverid`

For a solution to your question, I'd create a view that is something like:

```
create view conversations as 
SELECT senderid, recieverid FROM messages GROUP BY 1, 2
UNION
SELECT receiverid, senderid FROM messages GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Then, you can `select` from this view and get what you want.

As mentioned in the comment the `UNION` will give you distinct so you don't even need that...

Comment: *union* (ie not union *all*) already implements *distinct*